# PHP to search a string

Tags: php

I'm trying to use PHP to search a string and store certain elements in an array and then display the answers at the end. I'm trying to use the $match variable, but every time I do it, I get an undefined error for it.

My code:

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>states</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        $states = ('Mississippi Alabama Texas Massachusetts Kansas');
        $statesArray = [];

        //end in xas
        if (preg_match("/\b([a-zA-Z]*xas)\b/i", $states)) {
            $statesArray[0] = $match[1];
        }

        //begins with k ends in s. case sensitive comparison
        if (preg_match("/\b(K[[:alpha:]]*s$)\b/", $states)) {
            $statesArray[1] = $match[2];
        }

        // word start with m end in s
//        if(preg_match("/M/[[:alpha:]]*s", $subject))
        if (preg_match("/\b(M[[:alpha:]]*s)\b/", $states)) {
            $statesArray[2] = $match[3];
        }
        //ends in a
        if (preg_match("/\b([a-zA-Z]*a)\b/i", $states)) {
            $statesArray[3] = $match[4];
        }
        //starts with m
        if (preg_match("/\b(M[[:alpha:]]+)\b/i", $states, $match)) {
            $statesArray[4] = $match[5];
        }


        $print = print($statesArray[0]);
        print($statesArray[1]);
        print($statesArray[2]);
        print($statesArray[3]);
        print($statesArray[4]);

        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I suppose you're getting an undefined error because you're using an undefined variable `$match`. You don't define it until near the end of the code. Also you're using it incorrectly, you don't have that many capture groups in your regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `preg_match()` incorrectly. See the reference at http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php You need to pass the **$match** array and capture first or all matches you are interested in. The code below captures first match.

```
    $match = [];

    //end in xas
    if (preg_match("/\b([a-zA-Z]*xas)\b/i", $states, $match)) {
        $statesArray[0] = $match[0];
    }

    //begins with k ends in s. case sensitive comparison
    if (preg_match("/\b(K[[:alpha:]]*s$)\b/", $states, $match)) {
        $statesArray[1] = $match[0];
    }
```